# Making a soundboard and using mediaplayer android

Tags: android, button, global-variables, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I'm really new to programming and this is my first app attempt. I have a table layout with buttons and I want each button to play a sound (ie soundboard).
I can handle that fine, but I have 40 buttons now and each one I am calling a new instance of mediaplayer, so eventually I end up with too many and sound stops playing.

I have the following code for each button:

MediaPlayer MP1 = MediaPlayer.Create (this, Resource.Raw.sound01);

```
    Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
    button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        MP1.Start();
        MP1.Release();
    };
```

MediaPlayer MP2 = MediaPlayer.Create (this, Resource.Raw.sound01);

```
    Button button2 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button2);
    button2.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        MP2.Start();
        MP2.Release();

    };
```

etc.

I realize this is very repetitive and bad code. I have been told I need to use a global instance of mediaplayer and release it after the sound is played but I have no idea how to do either of those things.
I also found a suggestion to make something like this:

```
private int buttonIds = { R.id.button01, R.id.button02, R.id.button03, R.id.button04, etc };

private int soundIds =  { R.raw.sound01, R.raw.sound02, R.raw.sound03, R.raw.sound04, etc };
```

Any help with direct code examples would really help me out a lot, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This may help you out a bit...

```
    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4, R.id.btn5, R.id.btn6, R.id.btn7, R.id.btn8, R.id.btn9 };
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.s1, R.raw.s2, R.raw.s3, R.raw.s4, R.raw.s5, R.raw.s6, R.raw.s7, R.raw.s8, R.raw.s9 };


    // On Click Listener tells the button to play the sound.
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if (v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Matches the button with its correct sound???
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
```

Put this in your MainActivity.java's OnCreate method. Outside of the method type in the code "int selectedSoundId;" or an error will arise. Also, make sure you use buttons or you'll get another error. Hope this helps!!!